# How are MBIM transaction ID's supposed to be used?

Tags: usb, linux, cellphone, protocol, modem

## Situation

I am developing a product that will use [this Sierra Wireless HL7618RD Cat 1 LTE modem](https://source.sierrawireless.com/resources/#tags=HL7618RD). I am interfacing to the modem over USB using a small SoM running a Debian flavor of Linux. The modem is configured so that it appears to udev as having:

1. a serial interface (/dev/ttyACM[n]) for sending AT commands, and
2. a [Mobile Broadband Interface Model (MBIM) interface](https://usb.org/document-library/mobile-broadband-interface-model-v10-errata-1-and-adopters-agreement) (/dev/cdc-wdm[n])

I am interacting with the modem primarily over the MBIM interface using the tools from package '[libmbim-utils](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libmbim-utils)':

```
# apt policy libmbim-utils 
libmbim-utils:
  Installed: 1.18.0-1
  Candidate: 1.18.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.18.0-1 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

especially the '[`mbimcli`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/libmbim-utils/mbimcli.1.en.html)' and '[`mbim-network`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/libmbim/man/latest/mbim-network.1.html)' tools.

## Design Requirements

In short, the scripting that manages the cell module using `mbimcli` and `mbim-network` has to be fairly robust, good enough to handle things like dropped packet sessions and dropped registration, bad weather, blackouts, etc.

I cannot use ModemManager because I've had issues with it.

## My Question

How am I supposed to use MBIM transaction ID's (TRID) with `mbimcli`? When should I specify one, and when should I not?

A lot of examples, and [even in the source](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mobile-broadband/libmbim/blob/master/utils/mbim-network.in#L249) of the `mbim-network` utility, make use of the `--no-open=[$TRID]` and `--no-close` sometimes. Am I always supposed to specify a transaction ID every time I communicate with the modem in any way? What does it mean to specify one or not specify one? I can run, e.g.

`mbimcli --device-open-proxy --device=/dev/cdc-wdm0 --query-registration-status`

and get a perfectly good response. I did not acquire or specify a transaction ID.

## Research so far

The only other place I've seen this question directly asked is on the libmbim mailing list [here](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/libmbim-devel/2015-May/000582.html), and the guy that answers refers to the USB specification for MBIM [here](https://usb.org/document-library/mobile-broadband-interface-model-v10-errata-1-and-adopters-agreement). I understand what he is saying in his answer, and the purpose of a transaction ID given in the MBIM standard from USB.org.

I also see the `[mbim-network]()` source getting and recording a transaction ID as a temp file at /tmp/blahblah.